# Tensorflow-2.3.0 does not detect GPU

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am using **Ubuntu 20.04**.I upgraded Tensorflow-2.2.0 to Tensorflow-2.3.0. When the version was **2.2.0**, tensorflow was utilizing GPU well. But after upgrading to version **2.3.0** it doesn't detecting GPU.

I have seen this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63515767/tensorflow-2-3-0-does-not-detect-gpu) from stackoverflow. That was a problem of **cuDNN** version. But I have required version of cuDNN.

```
me_sajied@Kunai:~$ apt list | grep cudnn

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libcudnn7-dev/now 7.6.5.32-1+cuda10.1 amd64 [installed,local]
libcudnn7/now 7.6.5.32-1+cuda10.1 amd64 [installed,local]
```

I also have all required softwares and their versions.

### Cuda

```
me_sajied@Kunai:~$ apt list | grep cuda-toolkit

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

cuda-toolkit-10-0/unknown 10.0.130-1 amd64
cuda-toolkit-10-1/unknown,now 10.1.243-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
cuda-toolkit-10-2/unknown 10.2.89-1 amd64
cuda-toolkit-11-0/unknown,unknown 11.0.3-1 amd64
nvidia-cuda-toolkit-gcc/focal 10.1.243-3 amd64
nvidia-cuda-toolkit/focal 10.1.243-3 amd64
```

### Python

```
me_sajied@Kunai:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.2
```

### environment

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64"
```

### Log

```
me_sajied@Kunai:~$ python3
Python 3.8.2 (default, Jul 16 2020, 14:00:26) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
2020-09-13 21:28:37.387327: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
>>> 
>>> tf.test.is_gpu_available()
WARNING:tensorflow:From <stdin>:1: is_gpu_available (from tensorflow.python.framework.test_util) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` instead.
2020-09-13 21:28:48.806385: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2020-09-13 21:28:48.836251: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:104] CPU Frequency: 2699905000 Hz
2020-09-13 21:28:48.836637: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x3fde5f0 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-09-13 21:28:48.836685: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-09-13 21:28:48.840030: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2020-09-13 21:28:48.882190: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-09-13 21:28:48.882582: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x408bd90 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-09-13 21:28:48.882606: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce 930MX, Compute Capability 5.0
2020-09-13 21:28:48.882796: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:982] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2020-09-13 21:28:48.883151: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce 930MX computeCapability: 5.0
coreClock: 1.0195GHz coreCount: 3 deviceMemorySize: 1.96GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 14.92GiB/s
2020-09-13 21:28:48.883196: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-09-13 21:28:48.883415: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcublas.so.10'; dlerror: libcublas.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64
2020-09-13 21:28:48.885196: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2020-09-13 21:28:48.885544: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2020-09-13 21:28:48.887160: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2020-09-13 21:28:48.888134: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2020-09-13 21:28:48.891565: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2020-09-13 21:28:48.891603: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1753] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
2020-09-13 21:28:48.891625: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1257] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-09-13 21:28:48.891632: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1263]      0 
2020-09-13 21:28:48.891639: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1276] 0:   N 
False
>>>
```

Comment: Is your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` pointing to `/usr/lib/cuda-10.1/lib64` ? If this doesn't resolve it, please post any relevant environment variables that you've set in your `~/.bashrc`

Comment: What is the evidence that tf is not using the GPU? Also please include the output log from running tensorflow as it shows which CUDA libraries it is trying to load.

Comment: I did not add any relevant environment variables in `~/.bashrc`. @runDOSrun

Comment: I added the log. @Dr.Snoopy

Comment: Yes, now the problem is clear, cublas cannot be found: Could not load dynamic library 'libcublas.so.10'; dlerror: libcublas.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64 , your LD_LIBRARY_PATH is incomplete

Comment: It was working. Should I use runDOSrun's path? @Dr. Snoopy

Comment: What I mean by incomplete is that both paths should be there, just look where the .so files are and their names. Most cuda libs are in /usr/local/cuda/lib64 in your case.

Comment: Thank you. @Dr.Snoopy

Comment: Yes, it's `/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64`, had a typo there. I'll add it as an answer so you can mark the question answered.

Comment: This worked for me  'sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudart.so.10.2 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.so.10.1'

Answer (score 0):

In your `~/.bashrc` add:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64
```

If you have a different location for the lib64 folder, you need to adjust it accordingly.

As a side note, if you want to switch between multiple CUDA versions frequently you can also set an environment variable for a specific command directly in the terminal, such as e.g.:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64 python myprogram_which_needs_10_1.py
```

Then, if you want to switch to a different version, simply modify the path before the command.

Comment: what is this log? <br />
`2020-09-14 13:51:04.779092: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcublas.so.10'; dlerror: libcublas.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64`

Comment: @SajiedShahYousuf Your cuda has a different path then.

Comment: `me_sajied@Kunai:~$ whereis cuda
cuda: /usr/local/cuda
me_sajied@Kunai:~$ whereis cuda-10.1
cuda-10: /usr/local/cuda-10.1 /usr/local/cuda-10.2`

Answer (score -2):

> 2020-09-13 21:28:48.883415: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'libcublas.so.10'; dlerror: libcublas.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory;

In my case, this caused by being installed
`libcublas10` and `libcublas-dev` for **CUDA 10.2** by `apt upgrade`.

my solution about this problem at follows.

- my env. based on CUDA repos by NVIDIA.

```
$ sudo apt install --reinstall libcublas10=10.2.1.243-1 libcublas-dev=10.2.1.243-1
```

and preventing that appear upgradable candidate.

```
$ sudo apt-mark hold libcublas10
$ sudo apt-mark hold libcublas-dev
```